# solr sunspot unicode? characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, solr, sunspot

How do I use this file provided in sunspot (mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt)(or is this the one I need as well)? I need to be able to search for `"las pinas"` and include results like `"las piñas"` in my database. Meaning `n => ñ`? I have my config `schema.xml` like this for now:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and I have tried moving the `<charFilter>` setting around as well.

I have also searched and found various solutions mostly pointing to [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory) or [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) articles but those don't seem to work either.

Comment: How about this https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Spanish

Comment: can you check the URIEncoding  of the server...is it UTF-8...like URIEncoding="UTF-8"?

Comment: @RubyRacer: I've tried that out but didn't work as well.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti: I'm just working on my local. How do I do that? I use rails and I think puma.

Comment: @index:Are you using any container for your solr...you need add the URIEncoding there...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by container. But for now what we did was in `searchable` added an `I18n.transliterate` for now like this `text :address do [location, I18n.transliterate(location)] end`.

Comment: Please, make sure that after each modification to your schema, you reindex

Comment: @RubyRacer does this also include adding rules in synonyms.txt? Also, is running `rake sunspot:solr:run` automatically (re)indexes them? Or do I have to do `rake sunspot:solr:start` and `...:reindex` also?

Comment: After each change to the schema I believe you should run the `reindex` task. Also, you since you are altering the loaded xml I believe you should also restart, so, IMHO you should run three tasks: `stop`, `run` or `start` and `reindex`, in that order

Comment: `run` runs in the foreground so I can't do `run` and `start` together. Wondering if `run` automatically does `reindex`. Or should I just do `start-stop-reindex` routine?